# Group array by year

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am hitting a REST API which provides me a set of data contained in an array. The dates are strings.

The following is what the data looks like:

```
arr = [
    "2015-07-31",
    "2015-08-31",
    "2015-09-30",
    "2015-10-31",
    "2015-11-30",
    "2015-12-31",
    "2016-01-31",
    "2016-02-29",
    "2016-03-31",
    "2016-04-30",
    "2016-05-31",
    "2016-06-30",
    // MORE ITEMS...
]
```

How would  I achieve grouping this array by year (e.g. 2015: July, August, September etc. 2016: January, February, March etc.).

Would a custom pipe helps? And is it better to do the grouping in the controller rather than the service?

Comment: What kind of outcome do you expect? An array of arrays?, An object like `{"2015":[..], "2016":[...]}`?

Comment: something like {'2015': [], "2016":[]} etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to do it directly in the service.
So in your service you could have a private method `toGroupedYears(arrayOfDates)`, and then you could the rxjs operator map to do something like this:

```js
//myservice.ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
...
public getDates(){
  this.http.get(`${this.url}/dates`)
    .map( (dates) => this.toGroupedDates(dates.json()))
}
...
```

And in the `toGroupedDates` method you can have something like this:

```js
private toGroupedDates(array){
  // Extract year from arr
  let extractedYear = array.map((date) => {
    return date.split('-')[0];
  });

  // Get just the year list
  let yearsArray = new Set(extractedYear);


  // Group by year
  let filteredByYears = [];
  yearsArray.forEach((year) => {
    filteredByYears.push({ [year] : array.filter((_year) => {
      return _year.split('-')[0] == year; 
    })});
  });
  
  return filteredByYears;
}
```

Hope it help you :)

Comment: Where is that arr.filter supposedly come from? arr does not seem to be defined anywhere

Comment: This looks great but at the moment I get year : [...]. How could I extract the year too (so I end up with 2016: [..], 2015:[...] etc.)

Comment: Yes it was just a simple example on how you could do it. What output do you want ?

Comment: something like {'2015': [], "2016":[]} etc  should be fine! Thank you so much

Comment: ok , I edited my answer, you just have to add bracket arround the key `year` and it will take the variable.

Comment: Thanks you are a star!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144358/discussion-between-greatteacheronizuka-and-runit).

Answer (score 0):

i write an example for you
hope it could help you

```
  yearsGroup: any = {};
  groupByYear(arry: Array<string>) {
    arry.forEach((value) => {
      let date = new Date(value);
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      if (this.yearsGroup[year]) {
        this.yearsGroup[year].push(value);
      } else {
        this.yearsGroup[year] = [];
        this.yearsGroup[year].push(value);
      }
    });

  }
```

result:

```
{
  2015:[...],
  2016:[...]
}
```